# Why we use wrapper in decorator , when we can create decorator without wrapper?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, closures, decorator

i am reading python decorators and found them very useful , But i have a confusion which i tried to search on google and stackoverflow but couldn't found good answer , One questions is already asked on stackoverflow by same title but that question talk about @wrap and my question is different :

So what is the basic decorator template is :

```
def deco(x):
    def wrapper(xx):
        print("before the deco")
        x(xx)
        print("after the deco")
    return wrapper


def new_func(a):
    print("this is new function")

wow=deco(new_func)
print(wow(12))
```

Which result :

```
before the deco
this is new function
after the deco
None
```

So whenever deco return it call the wrapper function , Now what i am not getting is why we are using wrapper when our main goal is passing new_func as a parameter to deco function and then calling that parameter in deco function , if i try then i can create same thing without wrapper function here :

```
def deco(x):
    print("before the deco")
    a=1
    x(a)
    print("after the deco")




def new_func(r):
    print("this is new function")


wow=deco(new_func)
print(wow)
```

which result :

```
before the deco
this is new function
after the deco
None
```

So what is the use of wrapper in decorator ?

Comment: There's a difference between `print(wow(12))` and `print(wow)`... in the second case, you don't even get a function back.

Comment: There is difference. First way is returning function, and second way is returning nothing. Just add `print(type(wow))` after both of your calls and you'll see it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a question which may help.  Let's change `new_func` so that it
actually uses the parameter it's passed.  e.g.

```
def new_func(r):
    print("new_func r:", r)
```

Suppose also we have `another_func` which passes a parameter to `new_func`:

```
def another_func():
    new_func(999)
```

The question for you is, how could you write `deco` so that

- `another_func` continues to work without any change and
- `new_func` recieves whatever value is passed to it from `another_func`

?